# Not able to "install jq" and export API key for Planet with Anaconda3(Anaconda Prompt)

Tags: python, planet

I followed the steps of the PlanetLabs, but I encountered some problems.

Some libraries you need to install, when I enter the command "pip install jq" in the command line, it shows:

> Failed building wheel for jq,error: [WinError 2] The system can not
> find the file specified.

[image]

enter command

> export PL_API_KEY=XXXXXXX

I can't figure out where should I enter this command in, Python?CMD?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for error messages. Copy the whole error message as text edit your question and paste it into thee question then select the error message and use the `{}` button to formaqt it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`jq` is not a Python module so you'll need to install it in a way suitable for your operating system. See https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ for details.

Exporting your API key is something you will do in your shell. If you are on Linux, your shell is probably `bash`, but if you are on Windows, there are different ways to set an environment variable. In any case, you only need to do this if you are using Planet's command line tool, and even then there are other ways to provide your API key, such as running `planet init`. More information is here https://planetlabs.github.io/planet-client-python/cli/reference.html#general-options.

Answer (score 0):

`jq` is only distributed as a source package on PyPi, so if you want to `pip install jq` you will need an appropriate compiler setup.

You are using Windows so this can be complex.

An easier way would be to [download](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) a pre-compiled executable and put it somewhere in your executable search path - i.e. the directories listed in the [`PATH` environment variable](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20set%20user%20path%20variable) or install from the conda-forge Anaconda channel (since you are using Anaconda anyway) - `conda install -c conda-forge jq`

In Windows cmd.exe, the correct syntax is `SET PL_API_KEY=XXXXXXX` or you can add a [user environment variable](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20set%20user%20environment%20variable) then start a new cmd.exe prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [`jq`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jq)  from `conda` like this:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge jq
```

Assuming you have `conda` installed on your system. You run this from your terminal.